# What is the purpose of jackets having small zipperless back pockets just below the neck?

Tags: design, physical, ergonomics, wearables

I was a little bit surprised to find that my Bench-branded 100% polyester jacket had a little zipperless back pocket just below the neck, especially since placing something like keys there would make it uncomfortable to wear, and if anything was placed therein and the jacket turned upside-down, it would fall out.

So what is the purpose of this small pocket (the one I've stuck a pen in just to make it clear that it's an actual pocket)? More specifically, I would like to know what the user experience (UX) catered to by such design would be.

[image]

Comment: maybe just for looks? clothing companies are not known for UX development (with some except in highly specialized sport equipment)

Comment: Not sure how this applies to UX. Product design is interesting and there is some overlap. The question is - is there a functional utility for this pocket? Is it a way to tuck the hood out of the way but remain easily accessible? I don't know.

Comment: @mayo The hood is usually stored in a outside pocket along the base of the hood, at least in my wardrobe. Never seen this.

Comment: Yeah, outdoor wear is designed for convenience rather than just looks, and this jacket seems to fall under such category. But of course, that pocket would be to small to store the hood and would be on the wrong place (as the pocket is on the inside of the jacket, not on the outside). I still haven't figured out what it is for.

Comment: It's where you put your weed?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be hard to spot it if someone placed it there. Perhaps even a few condoms which would get damaged with heat if you were to put them in your wallet, given that the pocket is square. Or perhaps a secret paper note or other small folded paper items you wouldn't want others to know about. Who knows? Other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Maybe it’s a convenient location for hair bands which long-haired people lose all the time.

Comment: Seems like a good idea since the pressure from the hairband against the pocket walls would keep it from easily falling out, and the item would be right next to the person's pony-tail or so. Interesting suggestion.

Comment: Did this just expand the purview of this forum?

Comment: It's quite a good example of how aesthetic considerations crossover between the physical and digital worlds:  aspects of the design of an on-screen interface may have no usability consideration: the use of colours and graphics might be there just because they 'look good'. And the same applies to physical items.

Comment: So the black logo patch does not show through.  They seem to be big on branding the name.

Comment: Could be a way to get people to post questions about it for free advertising.

Comment: No, I don't work for Bench. Had it been any other brand I would have still posted the question; curiosity kills. ;-)

Comment: not sure what the actual purpose is but a condom fits the slot perfectly. Can never be too safe lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are certain sports where a neck-proximate pocket would make sense, but given the shape of this particular pocket I'm almost positive it's decorative and not functional.
For road cycling, where a rider is crouched, side or chest pockets are hard to reach so a neck-proximate pocket could provide betterUX.
For climbing, a climber's chest is often close to the wall and arms are often elevated, so it may be easier to reach a pocket at the top of the shoulder rather than side or chest pockets.
But for both these applications you would need a zippered or designed pocket to prevent stuff from falling out, which your jacket does not.
So I'm pretty sure it's form over function for you.

However, the pocket could be used to store certain types of items which are waterproof and don't easily fall out such as:

- A gecko, a small collection of earrings, paper clips, used chewing gum, a small folded UX feature request, a first generation IPod shuffle, a space pen, and [Richard Hammond](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hammond).

Comment: Well, it could just be that the pocket is there to draw more attention to the place where the brand name stands out (on the front side of the pocket). But perhaps in that place, having to open the zipper with one hand would make it hard for the person doing it who already has a bent arm reaching out behind their back. Perhaps that's why there's no zipper.

Comment: The reason I believe it's non functional is the shape of the pocket. It's possible to design zipperless pockets using kidney or L shapes which retain items better, but the pocket on your jacket is a rectangle so it would almost immediately fail field tests I think